# CSS remove hazy blue border from link in Chrome, prefer Firefox method

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, anchor

First: this is probably not a Bootstrap issue so I left "Bootstrap" out of the title, since it displays the way I would like in Firefox.

In Chrome, clicking on an edit icon in a table (or other links as well) results in a rather unpleasant hazy blue border, as shown:

[image]

In Firefox, the styling is unplanned but looks much nicer:

[image]

I have no special styling on my table besides Bootstrap's `table table-hover table-striped`.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:open('17');" ><img src="edit.png" /></a>
        <td>
    ...
```

How can I remove the hazy blue border from Chrome?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This effect is called the focus ring, and applies to any element that is given focus, either through a mouse click, a screen tap, or using the tab key on a keyboard.

This can be switched off in browsers by using the following:

```
a:focus, a:active {
    outline: none;
    -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

Be aware that switching this off makes it harder for users with accessibility needs to be able to make their way through your page. You can therefore use this styling to switch from the browser's default behaviour, to something more in keeping with the look and feel of your site, while embracing an audience with differing needs of accessibility. For example:

```
a:focus, a:active {
    outline: 4px dotted white;
    -moz-outline-style: 4px dotted white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the outline property, try removing the outline

```
.table-striped a:active, .table-striped a:focus{
      outline: 0;
     -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify `outline: none` CSS attribute on the type of element you want to disable it for. E.g.:

```css
a { 
    outline: none; 
}
```

Or

```css
input[type="checkbox"] { 
    outline: none; 
}
```